# Not complete deobfuscated code(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have deobfuscated the code, but there are still parts that are obfuscated, what programs or instruments can be used to deobfuscate parts like this:

```
    if (window[hasOwnProperty(id, 142, 145, 145, 114, 163, 146, 155, 161, 121, 150, 160, 161, 146, 155, 146, 159)]) {
      window[hasOwnProperty(id, 142, 145, 145, 114, 163, 146, 155, 161, 121, 150, 160, 161, 146, 155, 146, 159)]($(64012178998589, id), init, false);
    } else {
      if (window[hasOwnProperty(id, 142, 161, 161, 142, 144, 149, 114, 163, 146, 155, 161)]) {
        window[hasOwnProperty(id, 142, 161, 161, 142, 144, 149, 114, 163, 146, 155, 161)](hasOwnProperty(id, 156, 155, 154, 156, 162, 160, 146, 154, 156, 163, 146), init);
      }
    }
```

thus the function calls are like this now, is there a way to deobfuscate this?

Answer (score 0):

I gave the constants to a simple function as below:

```
function decode(a) {
  var i, x = '';
  for (i of a) {
    x += String.fromCharCode(i - 45);
  }
  return x;
}
var id = 46 + 45;
decode([id,142,145,145,114,163,146,155,161,121,150,160,161,146,155,146,159]) + '\n' +
decode([id,142,161,161,142,144,149,114,163,146,155,161]) + '\n' +
decode([id,156,155,154,156,162,160,146,154,156,163,146]);
```

this returns '.addEventListener', '.attachEvent' and '.onmousemove'.